# EntityFramework - map a complex property to a json (string) column

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have the following entity:

```
public class SampleClass
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public object Args {get; set; }
}
```

Because `Args` can be of different types and doesnt need to be queryable, I want to store it in the Database as a json string.

I know the following workaround would solve my problem:

```
public class SampleClass
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public object Args { get { return Json.Deserialize(ArgsJson); } set { ArgsJson = Json.Serialize(value); } }
  public string ArgsJson {get; set; }
}
```

But this is pretty ugly as it exposes information not related to the model and it contains logic again not related to the model.

What I would like to do, is something like that:

```
public class SampleClassMapper : EntityTypeConfiguration<SampleClass>
{
  public SampleClassMapper()
  {
    this.Property(e => e.Args).MapAs<string>(arg => Json.Serialize(arg), str => Json.Deserialize(str));
  }
}
```

Is there any cool way of doing so?

(I'm using .Net 4.0 with EntityFramework 5 and Sql Server 2008 if it helps)

Comment: This looks like `IUserType` in NHibernate. Can't be done in EF (yet?). Until then I think your solution is the best. You could put the serialize/deserialize calls in an utility class to have at least a little sense of separation of concerns.

Comment: In the solution you came up with you could make the ArgsJson property private so that it is not visible outside and [Ignore] the Args property. EF will be able to materialize to the private property but the property will not be visible outside. Since you told EF to ignore the Args property EF should not try doing anything with it. It is not possible to map object in EF.

Comment: @Pawel - but if the property is private, how would I map it?

Comment: you can use the overload that takes property name instead of lambda.

Comment: Today I realized I was not correct about being able to map to private properties with an overload that takes string. However it is still possible - take a look at this post: http://romiller.com/2012/10/01/mapping-to-private-properties-with-code-first/

Answer (score 1):

The way that you do is the only one available for now in EF. Currently EF Code First don't have any easy way to change the object serialization but this can be done modifying the EDMX file at runtime.

Comment: Not easy at all. I tried this for my Master course and need to modify the EF source code to get access to the low layers.

Comment: There is no EDMX in EF 7 so that may not be future proof.